# Coolpix L27 trigger mechanism

Tags: button, reverse-engineering, mechanical

I plan to do a 3d scanner with low-grade digital camera.
I opened a coolpix L27 and found this :

[image: Coolpix L27 trigger button]

Does anybody knows how this kind of button is called (may be it is normalised and finding a datasheet is possible)
Or would someone here have a service manual for the coolpix L27.

Thanks

So here is what I did :

[image]

il you look closely you can see in the 4th pictures that I inadvertedly put
some solder below the power button, this caused a short circuit.
However this camera is protected against short circuit and shut down immediatly.
Removing the solder with som "solder absorber" (tresse a dessouder in my language)
solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So by doing some poking around I found how it work myself

[image]

red pin are plugged to vcc wich is 3.3V
1 is auto focus
2 is trigger

to take a picture you have to put 3.3V on the autofocus pin
then 3.3v on the trigger pin.
Important, the autofocus still needs to be at 3.3V when you put 3.3V on the trigger pin.

Ps : be carefull with those nasty flash capacitor, my hands still hurts.